# I want to hide some select li items from a tab with css or js

Tags: javascript, css

I want to hide some tabs from a search tab. There is ul and li tab list. I want to hide some selected li item. There is no class or ID for using display:none. Here is the code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="st_hotel" class="">
   <a href="#st_hotel" aria-controls="st_hotel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria- 
    expanded="false">Hotel</a>
</li>
<li role="st_tours" class="">
    <a href="#st_tours" aria-controls="st_tours" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tour</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

suppose I want to hide the second li which is TOUR. how can I catch this li? there is no class or ID. Is it possible to catch this li with #st_tours role? or any other way? Please help me to solve this problem..

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('ul.nav-tabs > li')[1]` or `document.querySelector('li[role="st_tours"]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it has a `role` attribute we can select it using that.

```css
li[role="st_tours"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="st_hotel" class="">
    <a href="#st_hotel" aria-controls="st_hotel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria- expanded="false">Hotel</a>
  </li>
  <li role="st_tours" class="">
    <a href="#st_tours" aria-controls="st_tours" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tour</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```